# how to store the path of uploaded file into a variable using node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

this is my jade file:

```
    table(border='0' align='center')
      thead
       tr
        th
         form(action='/abc' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' )
          input(type='file' name='file')
          input(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large  
          value="upload"
```

now when i upload the file, the path of the uploaded file sholud be stored in a variable for further use.
this is what i tried:

```
    app.post('/abc', function(req, res) {
    var v = req.body.file;
    console.log(v);
```

when i tried to print the variable 'v' to check whether it is stored, it is printing undefined.
please let me know where i was wrong.

Comment: which node modules you use for parse multipart/form-data form

Comment: i've used formidable module.are there other modules to be used for multipart/form data?